# Within a draggable=true element, textareas and inputs need 2 clicks to edit in IE11

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, focus, draggable, internet-explorer-11

When using Internet Explorer 11, if you have textareas or input type='texts' within something that is "draggable=true", you will find that you have to double-click the fields in order to edit them.

Very simple Fiddle showing this (view in IE11):

http://jsfiddle.net/32h5gsvf/

```
<div draggable="true">
    <textarea>Some text here! Of course, you'll have to DOUBLE click to edit it.</textarea>
    <input type="text" value="Some text here too"/>
</div>
```

This is driving us nuts. We have a bunch of items that are draggable around the screen and they have a label field that is editable and in IE11 clicking into the field gives you no cursor or anything.

Is this intentional functionality, and does anybody have fixes?

Comment: I took a look at this and it seems like the first pointerEvent is getting triggered on the li, since that is what is interpreted as draggable. While you could technically bubble the pointerEvent on the textareas and the inputs so that the focus would trigger on them individually, that would defeat the purpose of adding a draggable area on the top level element through HTML5 APIs.

I would recommend adding a toggle button to trigger the whole area as draggable, and setting the draggable top level element as false.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Pen to explain my comment above. I think toggling this is the way to go, but if it doesn't meet your requirements then I would suggest moving away from default HTML5 draggable API and use a JS library to do this.

[IE 11 Draggable Toggle](http://codepen.io/KempfCreative/pen/dPmeqL)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="text-container">
        <textarea>Some text here! Of course, you'll have to DOUBLE click to edit it.</textarea>
        <input type="text" value="Some text here too"/>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="draggable" id="toggle-button"/>
```

JS:

```
var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
var textContainer = document.getElementById('text-container');
    toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(textContainer.draggable===false){
        textContainer.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        console.log("toggle true");
    }else
    if(textContainer.draggable===true){
        textContainer.removeAttribute("draggable");
        console.log("toggle false");

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What we've observed:

If we blur out and focus again the issue is resolved. 
However moving cursor position is still not accomplished. 
But at least does the trick for single click.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '#id input:text, textarea', function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).focus();
});
```